# DiscordJS cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a user command and I implemented a field that shows the users status, dnd, idle and online works fine and if the user appears offline it works fine but if the user is actually offline it gives the error `cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')`

Code:

```
        const statusTypes = {
            online: '<:online:313956277808005120> Online',
            idle: '<:away:313956277220802560> Idle',
            dnd: '<:dnd:313956276893646850> Do Not Disturb',
            offline: '<:offline:313956277237710868> Offline'
        };
        // embed field
                {
                    name: 'Status',
                    value: `${statusTypes[member.presence.status]}`,
                    inline: true
                },
```

Comment: `${statusTypes[member.presence.status]}` check if `presence` exists before using `presence.status`

Comment: wym, the other statuses work fine but when someones actually offline and not appearing offline it gives the error

Comment: The error means that `member.presence` is `null` so you need to account for that. You also do not need to wrap a variable in a template if there's no other text: `value: member.presence ? statusTypes[member.presence.status] : "offline"` or similar

Comment: ahh yep that fixes it thank you, makes a lot more sense now